# BeforeAll is not defined (old jasmine)

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I just installed `Protractor v2.0.0`.  I tried to add `beforeAll` to a test and got error

> ReferenceError: beforeAll is not defined

Looking at the the stacktrace I see jasmine 1.3.1 is a submodule of protractor:

> C:\Users\bmackey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21

`beforeAll` is introduced in jasmine 2.1.  I tried `npm i -g jasmine-before-all` to no avail.  How can I get this functionality to work?

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of jasmine.

Comment: @TonyBarnes -  How? Note the link.  Jasmine is part of protractor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Protractor is still using `jasmine1` by default. You have to set jasmine version in your config

```
framework: 'jasmine2',
```

You can find more information in the [reference configuration file](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js)

Comment: As of 4/10/2015 Protractor is updated to use [jasmine2](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/694a755b95aca067665bd17fae69797d370546ab) by default.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want for some reason to stay with `jasmine-1.x`, use [`jasmine-beforeAll`](https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll) package. It provides the same `beforeAll` and `afterAll` hooks.